# AngularJS | Validate email uniqueness using ng-blur and conditional variable

Tags: angularjs

Using ng-blur I am confirming uniqueness on an email address before the user can submit the form. I am expecting the code below to only show "That email address is taken" when it performs the `$http.put` and receives the 409 (which I confirmed is being sent). In all other instances the emailIsAvailable variable should remain true and I shouldn't see "That email address is taken". Unfortunately, The error displays whether the API sends 409 or 200.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : signup.email.$invalid && signup.email.$dirty}">

      <div>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="signupForm.email" ng-blur="validateEmail()" required>
        <span class="help-block has-error" ng-if="signup.email.$dirty">
          <span ng-show="signup.email.$error.required">Email address is required.</span>
          <span ng-show="signup.email.$error.email">Not a valid email address.</span>
          <span ng-hide="emailIsAvailable">That email address is taken.</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.emailIsAvailable = true;

  $scope.validateEmail = function() {

    var email = $scope.signupForm.email;

    console.log(email);

    if (email === undefined) {
      return;
    } else if (AuthService.validateEmail(email) === true) {
      $scope.emailIsAvailable = true;
      return;
    } else {
      $scope.emailIsAvailable = false;
      return;
    }
  };
```

**Service:**

```
validateEmail: function (email) {
  return $http.put('/api/user/validateEmail', {
    email : email
  })
  .then(function onSuccess (res) {
    return true;
  })
  .catch(function (res) {
    return false;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AuthService.validateEmail` function returns a promise.

You would need to refactor how you call it.

```
$scope.emailIsAvailable = true;

$scope.validateEmail = function() {
  var email = $scope.signupForm.email;

  console.log(email);

  if (email === undefined) {
    return;
  } else {
    AuthService.validateEmail(email)
    .then(function onSuccess (res) {
      $scope.emailIsAvailable = true;
    })
    .catch(function (res) {
      $scope.emailIsAvailable = false;
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't realize the promise has to be returned all the way through.